# Repeat AnimatorSet

Tags: android, animation

Is there a simple way to repeat a Android `AnimatorSet` (infinite)? Can I set a `AnimationListener` and restart the `AnimatorSet` by calling `start()` again?

My `AnimatorSet` contains two animations that are played sequentially.
So if I set the repeat mode of both single animation to repeat, than the first will be repeated while the second runs, right?

Answer (score 39):

set it's child object animators' repeat mode and count;

```
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART/REVERSE...);
```

This won't be able to be stopped, or cancelled, however, due to yet another bug.

clearly, I'm not a fan of the myriad ways in which you can animate things in Android, and have them all fail you in one way or the other. Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Yet there is another bug. If we set like this, and in animator set, we define to play for example first object animator, then second, the first animation repeats infinitely.

Answer (score 24):

There is an answer for the first two questions

> Is there a simple way to repeat a Android AnimatorSet (infinite)? Can I set a AnimationListener and restart the animatorSet by calling start() again?

Yes, there is:

```
mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

  private boolean mCanceled;

  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
    mCanceled = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    mCanceled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    if (!mCanceled) {
      animation.start();
    }
  }

});
mAnimationSet.start();
```

The answer for the third question, is no. The first animation will be repeated and after all repetitions the succeeding animation will be started.

Comment: AnimatorSet and AnimationSet are different.

Comment: I had to wrap the `animation.start()` located within `onAnimationEnd` inside a Runnable and `View.post()` it to the view I was trying to animate.  Calling `animation.start()` would only work one time.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't repeat AnimatorSet, you can only repeat of a single ObjectAnimator/ ValueAnimator

But you can use PropertyValuesHolder, so that you can make an ObjectAnimator from a set of PropertyValuesHolder

here's example

```
val translateY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, -100f, 100f)
val alpha = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 0.3f, 0.7f)
val scaleX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 0.8f, 1.2f)
val scaleY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 0.8f, 1.2f)
// and more

ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(myView, translateY, alpha, scaleX, scaleY).apply {
    interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    // duration of each animation
    duration = 500L
    // repeat infinite count (you can put n times)
    repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    // reverse animation after finish
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    // start animation
    start()
}
```

Comment: But if you want different durations for each animation, I think it's preferable to create multiple object animators, right?

Answer (score 3):

Set Infinite repeat count and restart / reverse repeat mode to all child animations

```
animatorSet.childAnimations.forEach {
            val animator  = it as ObjectAnimator
            animator.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
            animator.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART / REVERSE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet I've couldn't find a working solution with multiple animations, but one solution that works for me is to start again the animation after the ending.

P.S. I didn't handle the cancellation part here.

```
animatorSet.doOnEnd {
   it.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head - animation framework is source of pain, especially if you want to support 2.x. I usually had problems with sets trying to do anythig more complexKeep track of with `AnimationListener` kind-of "player". I keep track on which animation I play (like `int` etc) and then on `onAnimationEnd` I start another that should be in sequence. That  way I can easily "script" my sequence, and do not bother broken framework.

Comment: Hm, i never had such a problem. However what did you did in your last Animation onAnimationEnd() to repeat the whole animations. Can you simply call start of the first animation to repeat the whole animation workflow?

Comment: i started first one, zeroing my variable

Answer (score -2):

So, none of the above options are appropriate.

If you use:

```
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    if (!mCanceled) {
      animation.start();
    }
  }
```

you will end up getting stackOverFlow exception sometimes.

The best thing is to do something like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true && getActivity() != null) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            set3.start();
                        }
                    });
                    SystemClock.sleep(1200);
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Answer (score -4):

How about this?

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    if (!mCanceled) {
        animation.reset();  //<- added.
        animation.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `reset()` method for `Animator`.