# How to make a sequence of two animations in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, animation, kotlin, sequence

I have to animations in my Kotlin Scene and I want to make a sequence out of these two and I want the sequence to have infinite repetitions like looping the sequence.

```
//First Animation
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(block, "translationX", 50f).apply {
                duration = 500
                start()
            }

//Second Animation
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(block, "translationX", 0f).apply {
                duration = 500
                start()
            }
```

Thanks for your help!

Solution:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.WindowManager
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
 import android.animation.ValueAnimator
 import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
 import android.animation.AnimatorSet
 import android.animation.Animator

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        animateTogether(
        stripe.objectAnimate() // https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator
            .translationX(100f)
            .get(),
        stripe.objectAnimate()
            .translationX(-100f)
            .get()
    ).start()
}

fun animateTogether(vararg animators: Animator): AnimatorSet =
    AnimatorSet().apply {
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stripe, "translationX", 100f).apply {
            duration = 500
            start()
        }
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(stripe, "translationX", -100f).apply {
            duration = 500
            start()
        }
    }
```

Comment: put both of your animators inside an [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet).

Comment: You need to start the `animatorSet`, not both individual animators in it. I think you actually don't need the object animators inside `animateTogether`, which is why it was not part of my answer originally either.

Answer (score 0):

Try AnimatorSet

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
                as.playSequentially(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(...));
```

then you have two ways to loop it one set repeat mode on it's each animators taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622333/repeat-animatorset)

```
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
objectAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART/REVERSE...);
```

second use `AnimatorListenerAdapter` to listen when animation ends and restart the same animation.

```
mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
@Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
      super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
      mAnimationSet.start();
 }
});
mAnimationSet.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need a solution in Kotlin. @Bali

Comment: copy paste this code in your kotlin class in Android IDE it'll ask you to convert this code to kotlin. If you can't do that then i'll change it in kotlin. let me know

Comment: It doesn´t change automatically. @Bali

Comment: Just translate by yourself @JoyLucas

Answer (score 0):

I like to do the following:

```
fun View.objectAnimate() = ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(this) // https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator

fun animateTogether(vararg animators: Animator): AnimatorSet =
    AnimatorSet().apply {
        playTogether(*animators)
    }
```

And now I can do

```
animateTogether(
    someView.objectAnimate()
            .translationX(40.dp)
            .get(),
    otherView.objectAnimate()
            .translationX(-40.dp)
            .get()
).start()
```

For sequence, you can play with `.duration` and `.initialDelay` values of `Animator`, and can set repeat mode, etc.

Comment: I updated my answer. Did I implement the code right?

Comment: What do I need to import so I can use objectAnimate? I get the error: Unresolved reference: objectAnimate @EpicPandaForce

Comment: it's an extension function I probably should have added to the answer itself, but it's just `fun View.objectAnimate() = ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(this)`

Comment: Could you update your answer because I'm getting the same error again? Thanks! @EpicPandaForce